# Updating large table using oracle methods

Tags: sql, oracle

We have two large tables (40,00,000 rows each) and trying to update a column of one table from another. I have tried with 4 methods 1. Merge, 2. direct update 3. Cursor and 4. create table as select * from other one. Unfortunately none of them worked :-( Can someone please help ?

1. Merge

   ```sql
    begin
      merge into EVENT_LOG el
      using EVENT_ACTIONS ea
      on (el.EVENT_LOG_UUID=ea.EVENT_LOG_UUID  ) 
      when matched then update 
        set el.SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID = cast(
                                       regexp_replace(
                                         json_value(
                                           ea.ACTION_INPUT,
                                           '$.event.serviceInstanceId'
                                         ),
                                         '[^0-9]+',
                                         ''
                                       )
                                       as number
                                     );
   end;
   ```
2. Cursor

   ```sql
   DECLARE
     CURSOR ELUpdate IS
       SELECT cast(
                regexp_replace(
                  json_value(
                    ea.ACTION_INPUT,
                    '$.event.serviceInstanceId'
                  ),
                  '[^0-9]+',
                  ''
                )
                as number
              ) "SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID",
              event_log_uuid
       FROM   EVENTACTIONS ea
       WHERE  ea.ACTION_INPUT IS NOT NULL;
   BEGIN
     FOR i IN ELUpdate LOOP
         UPDATE EVENTLOG el
         SET  el.SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID=i.SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID
         WHERE el.EVENT_LOG_UUID=i.EVENT_LOG_UUID 
         AND el.SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID IS NULL;
     END LOOP;
   END;
   ```
3. ```sql
   select event_log_uuid,
          (SELECT unique
                  cast(
                    regexp_replace(
                      json_value(
                        ea.ACTION_INPUT,
                        '$.event.serviceInstanceId'
                      ),
                      '[^0-9]+',
                      ''
                    )
                    as number
                  )  
          FROM   EVENTACTIONS ea,
                 EVENTLOG el
          WHERE  ea.ACTION_INPUT IS NOT NULL            
          AND    el.EVENT_LOG_UUID=ea.EVENT_LOG_UUID
          )
   from   EVENTACTIONS_SVC.EVENT_LOG;
   ```

Comment: None of them worked ? What do you mean by that ? Are you saying that it takes more time or are you saying that it did not work at all ?

Comment: Is it like update is not working or the performance is bad ?

Comment: takes more time and timing out

Comment: @Prakash, do you have the indexes on event_log_uuid in both the tables ?

Comment: yes I have index on both tables @ranagal

Answer (score 0):

How about you try the below one:

```
    merge into event_log el 
    using 
    (
        select  t.event_log_uuid, json_value(t.action_input, '$.event.serviceinstanceid') jval 
        from    event_actions t
    ) ea
    on (el.event_log_uuid=ea.event_log_uuid ) 
    when matched then update 
    set     el.service_instance_id = to_number(translate(jval,'0123456789'||jval,'0123456789'))
    where   lnnvl(el.service_instance_id = to_number(translate(jval,'0123456789'||jval,'0123456789')));
```

Comment: Error report -
ORA-04031: unable to allocate 16777264 bytes of shared memory ("large pool","unknown object","qjsnSUCTX:subh","")

Comment: This is not the problem with the query. It is the problem with SGA. Kindly check with your DBAs for this.